# How can I change the color just for this page?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

http://cristianfertea.ro/event/sss/

This is code CSS:

```
  .qem-medium
{
background:#fed327 ;
}
```

For this page I want to be blue backgound:

For the rest I want to remain yellow pages.

I try but not working.

```
#8956 .gem-medium
{
background:red !important;
}
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `#8956 .gem-medium` makes no sense. Try: `body .qem-medium { background-color: red; }` (used inheritance to get element in more specific declaration which will overwrite more generic one - lousy, but works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific page has a specific class which would seem to be ideal

```
.postid-8597
```

So I would suggest

```
body.postid-8597 {
background-color: #fed327
}
```